# Can I open a aspnet core 2.0 solution created using VS17 in Win 10 Home on Mac using VS Code or VS for Mac?

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, windows-10

Can I open a aspnet core 2.0 solution created using VS17 in Win 10 Home on Mac using VS Code or VS for Mac?

Also since I’ve Win 10 Home edition I can’t run docker for windows and have to resort to Docker Toolbox. However when I launch a new aspnet core2.0 project in vs and select docker to build/run it, results in an error. How do I fix this? Has anyone of you encountered a situation like that?

Comment: I dont know about mac but vs2017 projects run on linux. Please add more info about the error you are getting.